# Algorithm for searching the neighbors neighbor of a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, performance, graph-traversal

Is there an algorithm to search a directed graph (tree) for its neighbors neighbor?

My current brute-force solution works as follows:

```
for each node n:
   for each child c of n
      for each parent p of c
         if (p != n)
           insert edge (p,n)
```

I am dealing with ca. 700.000 nodes each having between 1 to 1000 edges and currently I am facing too long running times: which is mainly due to the reason I am executing this algorithm on a graph database, since it would require too much memory.

Comment: Which graph database are you working on? Neo4j?

Comment: @c0da exactly. I am using it embedded with two Traversal objects: one walking down the nodes edges BFS to depth 1, and then one walking the the nodes back edges up BFS to depth 1.

Comment: In response to flags: algorithm design at the conceptual level (like here, with pseudocode, etc.) is on topic here.

Comment: @platzhirsch Sorry for the late reply, but have you tried Cypher, Neo4j's query language? I think that will be you best bet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are "for each child" and "for each parent" equally fast? If "for each parent" is slower, try this:

```
for each node p
  for each child c1 of p
     for each child c2 of p
       if (c1 != c2)
         insert edge (c1,c2)
```

EDIT: The above version creates a different result, a list of siblings. Now for another approach...

```
for each node c
  ps:=c.parents()   
  for each p1 in ps
     for each p2 in ps
       if (p1 != p2)
         insert edge (p1,p2)
```

Comment: But then I don't inspect the parent nodes, do I? I am sorry that I did not point this out more clearly, but since this is a directed graph, it's not the same relationship I am analysising.

Comment: Yes yes yes... a neighbour for you is someone with a common child... must fix it...

Answer (score 1):

Try substracting:

```
surroundings = list[]

for each node p
  for each child c1 of p
    for each child c2 of c1
      if c2 not in surroundings
        surroundings->add(c2) # Add everything, don't mind if it's on the border or inside.
    if c1 in surroundings
      surroundings->remove(c1) # Remove what's not on the border.
  if p in surroundings
    surroundings->remove(p) # Remove the initial node.

for each node border in list
  # Do whatever you want.
```

I'm sorry, I don't think you'll find anything smaller than an algorith in O(n³).